# Hello World is not displaying in react native android

Tags: android, react-native

Hi I have made `Hello World` program in `react-native` for android. I followed this https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html#content but it is not diplaying "Hello World" on screen when it launch app.

It is displaying empty screen. How can I fix this issue.

### index.android.js

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  Text
} from 'react-native';

export default class AwesomeProject extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Text>Hello World!</Text>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => AwesomeProject);
```

### Build Logs

```
E:\React Programming\AwesomeProject>react-native run-android
Starting JS server...
Running C:\Users\ch-e00925\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platform-tools/adb -s ZY223
8CX5L reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat install
Debug...
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42321Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoDrawee0110Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoFbcore0110Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoFresco0110Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipeline0110Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineBase0110Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookFrescoImagepipelineOkhttp30110Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookReactReactNative0350Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookSoloaderSoloader010Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareOrgWebkitAndroidJscR174650Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:bundleDebugJsAndAssets SKIPPED
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:dexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:validateDebugSigning
:app:packageDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:zipalignDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:installDebug
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'Moto G (4) - 6.0.1'
Installed on 1 device.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1 mins 9.699 secs
Starting the app on ZY2238CX5L (C:\Users\ch-e00925\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/pla
tform-tools/adb -s ZY2238CX5L shell am start -n com.awesomeproject/.MainActivity
)...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.awesomeproject/.MainActivity }
```

Comment: Try writing `"<code>"` instead of `<code>`. Just a suggestion...

Comment: @Fusseldieb I could not understand. What change you mean

Comment: In `index.android.js` I mean putting your code into `" "`

Comment: When I am trying to use same code here online simulator here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html  then it is working but not on android phone after I build it

Comment: You can try removing those newlines in: `import { AppRegistry, Text } from 'react-native';`, because it doesn't have it on your page you just showed me.

Comment: Same code has worked both in android emulator and device

Answer (score 5):

You need to first use `react-native start` to start the running packager and then use `react-native run-android` to start the emulator.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe its showing the text but you can't see because of the style issues. Try something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text, View } from 'react-native';

class HelloWorldApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Hello world!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Boxit', () => HelloWorldApp);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with expo  try adding a lot of characters to your text

```
<Text>Hello World!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!</Text>
```

You will see that the last part will be visible at top screen. The problem is basically the text is draw up out the display.(Status var hide the text!) If you look you could see the text back the status bar.